# How do you insert a record with a nullable column?

Tags: sql

How do you insert a record with a nullable column ?

Answer (score 8):

you omit that column from the insert statement, or set it to NULL

Answer (score 5):

if column2 is null

```
insert into table(column1, column3) values (1, 3)
```

or just include it

```
insert into table(column1, column2, column3) values (1, null, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

always name all columns in the INSERT.  If the table schema changes, your INSERTs are more likely to not break or work wrong.  As a result, so just put a NULL in:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col2) VALUES (1, null, 'A')
```

**EDIT**
there are many ways for problems to happen, here is just one example of how schema change breaks poorly coded INSERTs:

```
YourTable
col1  int      not null
col2  int      null
col3  char(1)  null
```

you code this in several places:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, null, 'A')
--OR this                             ---<<<<EDIT2
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, 'A') ---<<<<EDIT2
```

you change your table to:

```
YourTable
col1  int      not null
col1a int      null  default(0)
col2  int      null
col3  char(1)  null
```

what happens with your code? what values go in what columns?

if you had coded it this way

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col2) VALUES (1, null, 'A')
```

it will still work

Comment: I don't understand how adding all columns in will affect anything not breaking.  Can you give an example?

Comment: I thought you meant there was a difference between YourTable(col1, col3) and YourTable(col1, col2, col3).  I know your example is bad, I just thought you meant not including col2 was bad.

Comment: Of course, if you want to use the default value rather than explicitly using null then omitting the column is fine.

Comment: gotcha, I know it was way off topic, but thanks for clearing that up.  I'm not a DB guy ... as you can probably tell.

Comment: @KeeperOfTheSoul, it is hard to add a column, to an existing table, without setting a default value, which is why I put it in my simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You guys got me thinking:  move -1 to the null indicator, To insert a valid value, move 0 to the null indicator.